# How to limit the range of prediction in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I make a prediction in a dataset with stars range 1-5 using linear regression in Spark ml:

```
val lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
  .setFeaturesCol(featureCol).setLabelCol(labelCol)

// Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(dataFrame)
val result = lrModel.transform(data)
result.show()
```

But some predictions > 5:

```
+--------------------+-------+-----------+---+------------------+
|   topicDistribution|user_id|business_id|  s|        prediction|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+---+------------------+
|[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,...|   user|       item|  0|               0.0|
|[0.01514119038647...|      2|          1|  4|4.3475413742362665|
|[0.03940825720524...|      2|          4|  3| 6.916754074011433|
|[0.01514116632977...|      2|          1|  4| 4.245671097612515|
|[0.01786143737009...|      2|          5|  5| 4.753807934900515|
|[0.03943774853904...|      2|          4|  3| 6.973022108753978|
|[0.04868600587994...|      3|          2|  4| 3.648043391726578|
|[0.01515983372328...|      2|          2|  4| 4.246801262511743|
|[0.01786135762750...|      2|          1|  5| 4.753905610858851|
|[0.03940799263407...|      2|          4|  3| 6.970579591530296|
|[0.04868653016151...|      3|          2|  4|3.6480609281936154|
+--------------------+-------+-----------+---+------------------+
```

How can I limit the prediction in range [1,5]?
Or the way to transform the prediction to [1,5].

Comment: due to it's nature, a linear regression always provides unbounded predictions. Essentially, there remain two options. The first being to truncate/clip values to the desired range, The second could be to use a classification instead of a regression and rescale the results to the desired range.   However as a third option, you could also try to use a regression forest of decision trees, those can't predict values beyond ranges they haven't seen during training.But this solution is not the general way to tackle this common problem.

Comment: Is there a good way to truncate values to the desired range?

Comment: But I am finding some solutions in Spark.

Comment: yes, i just realized that you weren't using pyspark, sorry for the wrong hint. So far I haven't found a clipping function. But it should be easy to write one on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I use Spark SQL to filter and change the values:

```
def rangeColume(input:DataFrame, col:String):DataFrame={
input.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
val filter1 = ss.sql("select * from table where prediction >=1 and prediction <=5")
  .toDF("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s",col)
val filter2 = ss.sql("select * from table where prediction <1 ")
  .toDF("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s","prediction<1")
val filter3 = ss.sql("select * from table where prediction >5 ")
  .toDF("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s","prediction>5")
val filter4 = filter2.withColumn(col, lit(1))
  .select("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s",col)
val filter5 = filter3.withColumn(col, lit(5))
  .select("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s",col)
return filter1.union(filter4).union(filter5)
}
```

Someone has better solution maybe.

Comment: The function you should implement should do the following, take the values in your desired columns, if value > 5 set the value to 5, if the value is less than 1 set the value to 1 else simply return the value. Maybe try this on a simple dataframe containing the integers from -1 to 7 or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
val filter1 = ss.filter(" prediction")
                .toDF("topicDistribution","user_id","business_id","s",col)
```

This is the way you can try.